# Unable to restart rails Delayed Job on system reboot using cron

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, delayed-job

I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS`

Crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
@reboot ~/Projects/MyAPI/startworkers.sh;
```

startup script:

```
# /Projects/MyAPI/startworkers.sh

#!/bin/bash
source /home/server-linux/.bashrc

cd ~/Projects/LucyAPI

# Start background workers
bin/delayed_job --pool=tracking:2 --pool=emailverify:6 start
```

I expect there to be 6 delayed jobs running after reboot. However, none of them start. However, if I manually execute `start.sh` everything works as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need a /bin/bash as part of the crontab and also the absolute path to the user home. Crontab example:

```
@reboot /bin/bash -l -c '/home/your_user_name/Projects/MyAPI/startworkers.sh'
```

I would also strongly recommend using the whenever gem to handle your crontab. You can find it here [Whenever Gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever)